# Is it possible to get all users from a VSTS account programmatically?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We want to export all user accounts' info from our customer's TFS online account within a minimum of account name/E-mail address.

Using [REST API-- Get a list of accounts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/shared/accounts) still need the member ID or owner ID.

Is it possible to get the related info only with the account name or address programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are talking about VSTS. If you want to get a list of VSTS users (and other related information), you could use below API:

```
get https://{Account}.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview
```

Simply replace {Account} with your specific VSTS account name, then you will get a result as below include **Displayname**/**MailAdress**:

[image]

You could also be able to call the API with C#.

More details please refer this wonderful blog: **[GET A LIST OF VSTS USERS WITH APIS](https://blog.devmatter.com/get-a-list-of-vsts-users-with-apis/)**